# How to handle duplicate wake word in google action dialogflow?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I am building an action using DialogFlow for Google Action.

In general, We can start a session by "talk to {action_name}...", then we won't need to say the wake word again.

I was wondering how to handle the situation that user keep using "talk to..." after the session has already started?

For example:

> **User**: talk to `{action-name}`
>
> **Google**: Alright. Getting the test version of...(session started)
>
> **User**: ask `{action-name}` to ....
>
> **Google**: I can't understand...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've run into this once. If your intent has parameters, Dialogflow is often smart enough to ignore that and match intents.

Other times, if there's no parameters, this may cause Dialogflow to get tripped up. Using the History tab, you can see what users may run into issues. You can then add an extra training phrase and Dialogflow will update its model.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was wondering what did you mean by adding an extra training phrase? you mean like adding "talk to..." in the front of the original phrase?

Comment: Yeah I wrote about it in a [blog post](https://medium.com/google-developers/bringing-tabletop-audio-to-actions-on-google-through-media-responses-a48bbcd9a38?source=---------3------------------) and you can see I had to add "ask tabletop audio to play [lake]" to get the intent and entity matching correct.